# How do I declare a variable of certain type in Java?

Tags: java

I have this class called Imp.

```
public class Imp{

}
```

so how can I have this variable, let's say its called iimmpp, with the type Imp, and it should be able to access globally.

```
public static Imp iimmpp;
```

where should I put this statement? Thanks.

Comment: you want it to be accessible in the whole class?

Comment: yes, whole package to be specific

Comment: then you can use protected instead

Answer (score 0):

on your main class to create an object of imp,

type:

```
Imp iimmpp = new Imp();
```

Answer (score 0):

In any class, since it's public and static you can operate with it from any other class with classname.iimmpp;

For instance, in a class named Foo

```
public class Foo {
    public static Imp iimmpp;
}
```

You can access it with Foo.iimmpp from any other class on your application

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your main method to create an variable of type Imp.
Imp iimmpp = new Imp();

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it to be accessible i the class then you can just write :

```
public class Imp{
    public Imp iimmpp = new Imp();
}
```

when you instantiate this class you will still be able to retrieve the variable `iimmpp` because it has a `public` access.

Answer (score -1):

Put it in any other Static context where you will need to use it.

You can use it in any class that can see the Imp class (i.e. has imported the Imp class).

Simply put it between the brackets of the class declaration.  You can also put it inside of a static method, but then it will only be accessible within that method.

Comment: Way to downvote without adding any useful information or correction.